# how to debug a file in node_modules

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node and am playing around with SailsJS. I found what I think is a bug (reported it), but I wanted to have ago at debuging it myself.

I located the file that I need to investigate in the node_modules folder.

I tried putting a console.log in it to ensure I had the right one. Nothing happened.

So I tried placing log statements in several other files in node_modules that are at the top of the dependency tree. Nothing is printing out.

Do I need to do something to refresh the cache make this work? OR am I going about this in completely the wrong way!

Comment: does the project have its own tests? How do developer of the module add new features to it?

Comment: It doesn't make sense that your log statements won't run inside `node_modules`. I've done that plenty of times and it has worked fine. Have you tried creating a little sample app, adding a dependency to it, and putting log statements inside `node_modules`? I suspect it's something unique to your app. Perhaps `stdout` is being redirected?

Comment: @AlexFord That sounds like a good line of inquiry.  I'll investigate that.

Comment: @SystemicPlural your console.logs should work just fine, so, either they just aren't being reached, or you're redirecting the output somewhere other than the terminal.

Comment: Hello. Could you please provide a link to issue you reported ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if you think that an external module has a bug, the best approach is to clone it and write a test that shows which is the offending set of inputs.
SailJS is available on GitHub, so you can freely and easily contribute with a merge request if you find that you are right.
This way, you can adopt the same approach used by the project to test the code (as an example, using mocha).
In case the merge request will be accepted, while waiting for a new release on npm you can refer to your remote copy by means of the package.json file.

Comment: The bug is actually two layers down: sails -> anchor. So if I clone sails I will still have this dependency problem. I could clone anchor. But I have no idea what data is getting passed to it. The quickest way to find out is to console it out. How do I do that?  I need the nested dependencies to work out what is going wrong

Answer (score 0):

first of all, if you believe the log message should be printed out, then make sure you re-build the code after adding logs as your watch option most likely skip the node_module files.

Also, if you want to have a proper debug, consider using '[npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-link)' for debugging.

in a nutshell:

```
// in package
npm install && npm link
// in app
npm link packageName
```

if your package also have some dependency you need to debug:

```
//in package 1
npm link
// in package 2
npm link package1Name
npm link
//in app
npm link package2Name
```